# Flex PHP Reset DataGrid Records from WebService Results

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, zend-framework, datagrid

I've been stuck for the last 2 days trying to figure out this problem that I think is a standard occurrence for Flex developers.  I'm using Flex 4.5 with PHP Zend webservice framework. Basically, I have 2 DataGrids that can drag and drop between each other.  At the initializing of the component, I call a webservice to populate the top DataGrid.  Then the user can drag rows to the bottom DataGrid that get processed and saved later on.

My problem is that I want to have a reset button (or cancel button), that will take the user to a new component in the ViewStack, and if they return to the component with the DataGrids, the top DataGrid has the original records and the bottom DataGrid is empty.  I just can't figure out a good way to repopulate the top DataGrid.  I can clear it, but it doesn't seem to refresh with the original data.

I've tried unsuccessfully to call the webservice again and set the dataprovider to the new lastResult token.  I've also tried unsuccessfully to copy the results of the initial webservice call to an ArrayCollection and simply set a Bindable variable to that ArrayCollection (or a backup of that ArrayCollection holding original records).  Does anyone have a simple solution?  Thank you!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                        xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
                        xmlns:usersservicecreatetherapist="services.usersservicecreatetherapist.*"
                        width="910" height="894" backgroundColor="#F4F79B"
                        currentState="createTherapistState"
                        fontSize.createTherapistState="16">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                import mx.events.CloseEvent;
                import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
                import mx.rpc.IResponder;
                import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
                import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
                import mx.rpc.remoting.mxml.RemoteObject;

                import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

                protected function process_therapistDetailsForm():void
                {
                    currentState="reviewTherapistState";
                }

                protected function cancel_therapistDetailsForm():void
                {
                    resetCreateTherapistFormsGrids();
                    parentDocument.switchView("overviewComponent");

                }

                protected function patientGridInitialize():void
                {   
                    getUsersByUserType('Active');

                }

                // Reset functions
                protected function resetCreateTherapistFormsGrids():void
                {
                    // logic to reset grid ??

                }


                protected function getUsersByUserType(userStatus:String):void
                {
                    getUsersByUserTypeResult.token = usersServiceCreateTherapist.getUsersByUserType(userStatus);
                }

            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <s:states>
            <s:State name="createTherapistState"/>
            <s:State name="reviewTherapistState"/>
        </s:states>
        <fx:Declarations>   
            <s:ArrayCollection id="genderArray">
                <fx:String>Male</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Female</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayCollection>

            <s:ArrayCollection id="usStatesAbbrArray">
                <fx:String>AK</fx:String>
                <fx:String>AL</fx:String>
                <fx:String>AR</fx:String>
                <fx:String>AZ</fx:String>
                <fx:String>CA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>CO</fx:String>
                <fx:String>CT</fx:String>
                <fx:String>DC</fx:String>
                <fx:String>DE</fx:String>
                <fx:String>FL</fx:String>
                <fx:String>GA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>HI</fx:String>
                <fx:String>IA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>ID</fx:String>
                <fx:String>IL</fx:String>
                <fx:String>IN</fx:String>
                <fx:String>KS</fx:String>
                <fx:String>KY</fx:String>
                <fx:String>LA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MD</fx:String>
                <fx:String>ME</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MI</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MN</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MO</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MS</fx:String>
                <fx:String>MT</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NC</fx:String>
                <fx:String>ND</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NE</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NH</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NJ</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NM</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NV</fx:String>
                <fx:String>NY</fx:String>
                <fx:String>OH</fx:String>
                <fx:String>OK</fx:String>
                <fx:String>OR</fx:String>
                <fx:String>PA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>PR</fx:String>
                <fx:String>RI</fx:String>
                <fx:String>SC</fx:String>
                <fx:String>SD</fx:String>
                <fx:String>TN</fx:String>
                <fx:String>TX</fx:String>
                <fx:String>UT</fx:String>
                <fx:String>VT</fx:String>
                <fx:String>VA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>WA</fx:String>
                <fx:String>WI</fx:String>
                <fx:String>WV</fx:String>
                <fx:String>WY</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
            <s:CallResponder id="getUsersByUserTypeResult"/>
            <usersservicecreatetherapist:UsersServiceCreateTherapist id="usersServiceCreateTherapist"
                                                                     fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                                                     showBusyCursor="true"/>

        </fx:Declarations>

        <!-- Step 1: Fill out form of patient details -->
        <s:Scroller left="10" top="10" bottom="0" 
                    width="450">
            <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:Form id="therapistDetailsForm" 
                        width="100%" 
                        color="#2582A4"
                        enabled.reviewTherapistState="false">
                    <s:FormHeading width="358" 
                                   label="Step 1: Create a new therapist" 
                                   fontWeight="normal"/>
                    <s:FormItem width="100%"
                                label="First Name" 
                                fontSize="14"
                                required="true">
                        <s:TextInput id="firstName" 
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:FormItem width="100%" 
                                label="Middle Name" 
                                fontSize="14">
                        <s:TextInput id="middleName"
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:FormItem width="100%" 
                                label="Last Name" 
                                fontSize="14"
                                required="true">
                        <s:TextInput id="lastName" 
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:HGroup width="100%" 
                              height="55">
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="Gender" 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:DropDownList id="gender"
                                            dataProvider="{genderArray}"
                                            selectedIndex="0"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="D.O.B." 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:TextInput id="birthday"
                                         width="100%"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                    </s:HGroup>
                    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="55">
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="Email" 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:TextInput id="email"
                                         width="100%"/>
                        </s:FormItem>                   
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="Phone" 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:TextInput id="phone"
                                         width="100%"/>
                        </s:FormItem>

                    </s:HGroup>
                    <s:FormItem width="90%" height="47" 
                                label="Address" 
                                fontSize="14"
                                required="true">
                        <s:TextInput id="address" 
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:FormItem width="90%" height="47" 
                                label="City" 
                                fontSize="14"
                                required="true">
                        <s:TextInput id="city" 
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="52">
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="State" 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:DropDownList id="usStates"
                                            dataProvider="{usStatesAbbrArray}"
                                            selectedIndex="20"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="Zip" 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:TextInput id="zip"
                                         width="100%"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                    </s:HGroup>
                    <s:FormItem width="100%" 
                                label="Race" 
                                fontSize="14">
                        <s:TextInput id="race"
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:FormItem width="100%" 
                                label="National Origin" 
                                fontSize="14">
                        <s:TextInput id="nationalOrigin"
                                     width="100%"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="52">
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="Height " 
                                    fontSize="14"
                                    required="true">
                            <s:TextInput id="tHeight"
                                         width="78"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:FormItem width="50%" 
                                    label="Weight" 
                                    fontSize="14">
                            <s:TextInput id="tWeight"
                                         width="100%"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                    </s:HGroup>
                    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="50">
                        <s:FormItem>
                            <s:Button id="nextTherapistDetails"  x="501" y="50" label="Next"
                                      click="process_therapistDetailsForm();"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:FormItem>
                            <s:Button id="cancelTherapistForm"  x="501" y="50" label="Cancel"
                                      click="cancel_therapistDetailsForm();"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:Form>
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:Scroller>

        <s:Scroller includeIn="reviewTherapistState" right="10" top="10" bottom="0" width="442">
        <!-- Step 2: choose patients to be assigned to therapist -->
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:Form id="assignPatientsForm" width="100%" height="436">
                <s:FormHeading label="Step 2: To assign patients drag them to bottom table."/>

                <!-- Drag and drop of the patients -->
                <mx:ApplicationControlBar width="402"
                                          horizontalAlign="center">
                    <s:Label text=" Available Active Patients"
                             color="#000000"
                             fontFamily="Verdana"/>
                </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

                <mx:DataGrid id="patientList" 
                             width="430" height="181" 
                             allowMultipleSelection="true"
                             color="#000000" 
                             dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" 
                             fontSize="14"
                             dataProvider="{getUsersByUserTypeResult.lastResult}">

                    <mx:columns>                    
                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="fname"  
                                           headerText="First Name" 
                                           width="100"/>        
                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="lname"  
                                           headerText="Last Name" 
                                           width="100"/>    
                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="birthday"
                                           headerText="D.O.B."
                                           width="95"/>                 
                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="gender" 
                                           headerText="Gender"
                                           width="70"/>                 
                        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="weight" 
                                           headerText="Weight"
                                           width="65"/>                 
                    </mx:columns>               
                </mx:DataGrid>

                <s:HGroup width="100%" height="155">
                    <mx:DataGrid id="selectedPatientList" 
                                 width="300" height="154"
                                 allowMultipleSelection="true" 
                                 dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" 
                                 color="#000000"
                                 creationComplete="patientGridInitialize();" 
                                 fontSize="14">

                        <mx:columns>                    
                            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="fname"  
                                               headerText="First Name" />   
                            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="lname"  
                                               headerText="Last Name" />
                        </mx:columns>               
                    </mx:DataGrid>
                    <s:VGroup width="100%">

                        <s:FormItem width="100%">
                            <s:Button id="saveTherapistForm" y="50" left="0" right="0" label="Save"
                                      click="process_therapistDetailsForm();"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:FormItem width="100%">
                            <s:Button id="backTherapistDetails" y="50" left="0" right="0" label="Go Back"
                                      click="currentState='createTherapistState';"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                        <s:FormItem width="100%">
                            <s:Button id="cancelTherapistForm2" y="50" left="0" right="0" label="Cancel"
                                      click="cancel_therapistDetailsForm();"/>
                        </s:FormItem>
                    </s:VGroup>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:Form>
        </s:VGroup>
        </s:Scroller>


    </s:NavigatorContent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the spark datagrid if you can.  Makes it a lot faster.

But essentially, your main issue is because you're binding the lastResult of your service directly to the datagrid.  What you should be doing is saving that result somewhere in your class and copy the data over so that you have the modified, unsaved version and the original.  From there it's easy to just swtich back to the original data (`yourDatagrid.dataProvider = originalData;`).  Check out my [blog article](http://www.michelboudreau.com/2009/12/11/keeping-model-state-in-components/) about this.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!  Such a easy solution and it costs me 2+ days of confusion.  :)